# Как менять имя файла при записи из переменной?

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, циклы

помогите пожалуйста:

> Python 3.10.4

Записываю в список все ссылки:

```
urls = []

with open("source-page.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp, "lxml")
    soup_find = soup.find_all("a", class_='blogArticleCut')

    for a in soup_find:
        urls.append("https://blog.winetime.moscow" + a['href'])
```

Хочу сохранить несколько фалов с наименованием ссылок

```
for urls in urls:
    file_d = "".join(urls) + ".html" # тут из списка в строки перевожу 
    # открываем страницу из списка [urls]
    s = Service("/Users/dmitrijkodolov/PycharmProjects/scarper_wt/chromedriver")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.get(urls)
    time.sleep(3)
    # ищем элемент body и скролим вниз
    search_page = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='body')
    if search_page:
        with open(f"{file_d}", "w") as file: #!!! ПРОБЛЕМА ТУТ !!!
            file.write(driver.page_source)
            print("Спарсили" + " " + urls)
        driver.quit()
    else:
        search_page.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        print("Не могу найти элемент...")
        driver.quit()
```

Вылезает ошибка:

> File "/Users/dmitrijkodolov/PycharmProjects/scarper_wt/scarper.py", line 88, in 
> with open(f"{file_d}", "w") as file:
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://blog.winetime.moscow/second_wines_labels.html'

Куда смотреть, что делать? Может библиотеку посоветуете? Пробовал через `os.rename()`. Видимо, тут ошибка в логике, но самостоятельно не могу ее обнаружить.

Comment: "/" в имени файла.

Comment: file_d переменную посмотри, там ж жесть

Comment: urls in urls вообще жесть))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"/" воспринимается как путь к файлу, поэтому решил заменой "/" на "."

```
    if search_page:
        with open(i.replace("/", ".") + ".html", "w") as file:
            file.write(driver.page_source)
            print("Спарсили" + " " + i)
        driver.quit()
```